# Title Attributes and Accessibility

Tags: seo, html5, accessibility, title-attribute

I've been looking into accessibility recently and have read mixed articles regarding whether or not the title attributes should be included. It seems that there's a pretty good consensus that adding title attributes mean nothing for SEO but for screen readers and such I wasn't sure.

This is regarding the `title` attribute, not to be confused with the `<title>` tag, for example:

```
<a href="#" title="Some description">Link Title</a>
```

Doing a quick Google search on "Title Attribute and Accessibility" comes up with a list of conflicting articles on whether it's still a good practice or not. An ideal answer would be one that has links to back up their assertions to the following questions:

Should I still be using the title attribute? Is there ever a case where I should / shouldn't be including the title attribute on anything? Are there any negative effects if I leave the `title` attribute out?

Comment: Sorry but there is already a vast amount of questions already on Pro Webmasters regarding [the use of ALT and TITLE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=title+alt) for both accessibility and SEO value.

Comment: @SimonHayter No problem, I did search for title tag specifically but didn't see anything regarding it's use for Accessibility, only SEO.

Comment: It's no problem at all, in terms of title and screen readers see: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16173/whats-the-importance-of-the-title-tag/16181#16181 and most likely many more questions and related answers on Pro Webmasters. If you believe your question is more sided towards 'screen readers' and you have questions regarding screen readers then you could form a unique question based on that, but currently SEO value has been asked and answers more times than I can count.

Comment: @SimonHayter the linked question ( and the linked search ) seem to point mostly toward the `<title>` tag and not specifically the title attribute ( on things such as links and images ). The search mostly regards SEO but my main interest is it's use for Accessibility. I've found a couple article that say [don't use title attributes](https://silktide.com/i-thought-title-text-improved-accessibility-i-was-wrong/) and some that say [do use them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382768/accessibility-of-the-title-attribute). I'm not sure if that helps clarify my question, I can add this info.

Comment: If it's still duplicate I understand and will keep searching through the exchange to see if I can find any answers that specifically discuss the importance of the title attribute and Accessibility versus prolonging the comments.

Comment: Yep, keep searching, I'm sure your find something. But also just so you know often questions that start with 'the importance of' 'best practices' and 'how to' can be too board, when asking a question on Pro Webmasters ensure your question is not duplicate, and your asking something very specific and not open ended.